# Remove Duplicates numbers in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file called Sparrow.txt and its content is follows

```sh
ENV-NAME|ACTIVE-SITE|MCM|BDD|ELOW|OPT|MSP
======|===========|========|========|=======|=========|========
EAST| PROD | 2311| 2312 2312 | 2313 2313 | 2314 2314 | 2315 2315
EAST| STAGE | 2311 | 2312 2312 | 2313 2313 | 2314 2314 | 2315 2315
```

I want to remove the duplicates in the file and following should be the output

```sh
ENV-NAME|ACTIVE-SITE|MCM|BDD|ELOW|OPT|MSP
======|===========|========|========|=======|=========|========
EAST| PROD | 2311| 2312 | 2313 | 2314 | 2315 
EAST| STAGE | 2311 | 2312 | 2313 | 2314 | 2315
```

I have tried to sort and uniq but that didn't work

Comment: does the file really contain those `"`? Did you try processing it with `awk -F'|' ...`?

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates across different fields, like `2311 | 2312 2311` becomes `2311 | 2312`

Comment: FYI, you can combine `sort` and `uniq` into `sort -u`. Since they both operate on lines, you'll need to translate the spaces into newlines, remove the duplicates, then convert it back to a single line. `tr ' ' '\n'  <<<"$variable" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: @Farvadona there are No `"`

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `perl` :

```
perl -pe 's|\b([0-9]+) \1\b|\1|g' Sparrow.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( split($i,t," ") > 1 ) {
            $i = " " t[1] " "
        }
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ENV-NAME|ACTIVE-SITE|MCM|BDD|ELOW|OPT|MSP
======|===========|========|========|=======|=========|========
EAST| PROD | 2311| 2312 | 2313 | 2314 | 2315
EAST| STAGE | 2311 | 2312 | 2313 | 2314 | 2315
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got GNU Sed, try:

```
sed 's/\<\([[:digit:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+\1\>/\1/g' Sparrow.txt
```

Comment: Using `-E` will save you a few backslashes